# Using a function key in a datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, keypress

I have application using a datagridview.  I need to allow the user to press F8 to add a blank row to the grid.  How can I tell when F8 was pressed?

Comment: Can you give us some piece of your code?

Comment: datagridview and tag